# tensorflow object api faster_rcnn_resnet101 training image resizing

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am currently using the Tensorflow Object API to train my own classes. I am retraining using the faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco model.

To create the training data, I used RectLabel to put bounding boxes around objects in approx 100 images. Each image has approx 30 classes in them, for a total of 40 classes present in all the images.

My images are 1920 × 1080 in size. The images are produced by pulling random frames from videos of the objects I would like to detect.

My issue is that I am not getting any detections (Tensorboard is not showing any) and I think it is because the training images are being resized and the objects in the images are getting too small. I am using the default faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco.config file with no changes (except for locations to the data).

Would it be a good idea to perform a random crop of the images (instead of resizing as below) so as to keep the object size the same for training?

```
image_resizer {
  keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
    min_dimension: 600
    max_dimension: 1024
  }
```

Could there be another issue I am overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

I used to deal with a object detection problem,I got nothing at first.I trained the model for two more days ,I got the right results.

more training and more data may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried that the resizing is making the objects to small to detect, you can use a larger input resolution. Theoretically you can do it only on your training data, but I'm not sure it would give good result with such tiny training set.
Instead, you can first fine-tune the pre-trained model with the same dataset (COCO?) on the larger input resolution, and only then fine-tune it on your training data with the larger resolution.
This way, the model will theoretically first learn to adapt to the larger resolution, and then will learn your classes.

I would also like to side with Friday2013 and suggest to get more training data, possibly more augmentation, and then more training time. Only training longer might not help if you still train on the same small amount of images, since you would get overfitting.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback on this. I am using Google Cloud ML and my first mistake was using the BASIC tier instead of the BASIC_CPU tier for training. Once I did this, things moved along much faster and I started to get good detection's.